# MongoDB Aggregation get key value based on another key value within an array

Tags: python, aggregation-framework, pymongo

in the context of the aggregation framework and considering the following simplified document structure stored in a MongoDB collection:

```
[
    { 'reference': 'ReferenceStr',
      'subgroup': [ { '#': 1, 'param': 123},
                    { '#': 2, 'param': 456},
                    { '#': 3, 'param': 789}
                  ],
      'group': [ {'#': 1, 'start': 1, 'end': 2},
                 {'#': 2, 'start': 3, 'end': 3} ],
    }
]
```

Knowing a condition on $group.# (let's say $group.#=1), I want to use the associated value of $group.end (here 2) to get the value of $subgroup.param corresponding to $subgroup.#=$group.end

I would like to return:
{'reference': 'ReferenceStr', 'var': 456}

So far I have only:

```
db_collection.aggregate([
                          { '$project' : {
                                           'reference' : '$reference',
                                           'var' : {
                                                     ...
                                                   }
                                         }
                          }
])
```

Are $indexOfArray and $arrayElementAt my only hope?
I get lost in the structure.

Any help would be very appreciated, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform `$lookup` to do a self lookup by using `end` in your specified group. Then in the sub-pipeline, you can filter out the expected sub-group by `$match` the `$group.end`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$group"
  },
  {
    // input your group condition here
    $match: {
      "group.#": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        "end": "$group.end"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$unwind": "$subgroup"
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                // find the subgroup that matches your condition
                {$eq: [
                  "$$end",
                  "$subgroup.#"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "as": "selfLookup"
  }
},
{
  "$unwind": "$selfLookup"
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    reference: "$selfLookup.reference",
    var: "$selfLookup.subgroup.param"
  }
}
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F9SMxxNvuxh) for your reference.